# iOS 7 How to animate StatusBarStyle from DefaultContent to LightContent

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewanimation, uistatusbar

I am trying to transition the status bar style from **UIStatusBarStyleDefaultContent** to **UIStatusBarStyleLightContent** using a UIView animation, however, the style just switches with no fade animation. I figured that setting the style using the following would work:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 } completion:nil];
```

I am not sure how to get what I want to happen. Basically, my content changes from dark to light so I need to change the status bar color. By default it doesn't work the way I want. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
  
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how it's done.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

Here is the [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW15)

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Sometimes you just try to do an animation block and then you find that parameter, damn you **animated**

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you can't do what you're trying to do.

The docs say that the animation when you call setStatusBarStyle is a slide animation:

> statusBarStyle The current style of the status bar.
>
> @property(nonatomic) UIStatusBarStyle statusBarStyle Discussion The
>   value of the property is a UIStatusBarStyle constant that indicates
>   the style of status. The default style is UIStatusBarStyleDefault. The
>   animation slides the status bar out for the old orientation and slides
>   it in for the new orientation.